# AmazonS3Client and credentials

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to deal with being able to read a file hosted in S3 using a Java application. I have added the AmazonS3Client but it fails with when it goes to ProfileCredentialsProvider. I have my AWS credentials at C:/User/.aws (default), credentials are found but the following error is thrown: "Invalid property format: no '=' character". My credentiasl (download from Amazon) is a csv file separated by commas. Please can anybody tell me if I have to modify this file? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *will* need to change the format of that file; the `ProfileCredentialsProvider` class does not expect the CSV format, but instead expects the file to be formatted like one shown in the [`ProfilesConfigFile`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfilesConfigFile.html) docs:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=testAccessKey
aws_secret_access_key=testSecretKey
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If anybody ever stumbles upon this issue and cannot find any solutions, check if you have inline comments like `[some-profile] #inline comment` in your credentials file. Seems like it is not supported and breaks everything.